# Efficient and Succinct Vector Transformation of Weekly to Daily hourly Data in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I've got a working function, but I'm hoping there is a more succinct way of going about this.

I have a dataset of events that are captured with the hour of the week they occurred in. For example, 4 AM on Sunday= 4, 4 AM on Monday = 28 etc. I want to analyze this data on a daily basis. For instance, all of the events that happen between 8 and 10 am on any day.

To do this I have built a function that returns a dichotomous value for the given range for an ordered list. Function two_break accepts an ordered list of integers between 0:168 representing the hours of a week and a range (b1 and b2) for the desired periods of a 24 hour day. b1 and b2 divide the range of the 24 hour day that are desired. i.e. if b1=8 and b2=10 two_break will return all all values of 9, (9+24)=33, (9+48)=57...etc. as 1 and all others 0.

```
two_break <- function(test_hr,b1,b2){

   test_hr<-ifelse(test_hr==1,1.1,test_hr)
   for(i in 0:6){
     test_hr<-ifelse(test_hr> (b1+24*i) & test_hr< (b2+24*i), 1 ,test_hr)
  }
   test_hr<-ifelse(test_hr==1,1,0)
   return(test_hr)
}
```

This function works fine, but I'm wondering if anybody out there could do it more efficiently/succinctly.

See full code and data set at my github: [anthonyjp87](https://github.com/anthonyjp87/R_Cheats) 168 hr transformation file/data.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use integer division `%/%` to capture the day of the week, and modulus, `%%` to capture the hour in the day:

```
weekHours <- 1:168

# return the indices of all elements where the hour is between 8AM and 10AM, inclusive
test_hr <- weekHours[weekHours %% 24 %in% 8:10]
```

Note that midnight is represented by 0. If you want to wrap this into a function, you might use

```
getTest_hr <- function(weekHours, startTime, stopTime) {
                  weekHours[weekHours %% 24 %in% seq(startTime, stopTime)]
              }
```

To get the day of the week, you can use integer division:

```
# get all indices for the third day of the week
dayOfWeek3 <- weekHours[(weekHours %/% 24 + 1) == 3]
```

To get a binary vector of the selected time periods, simply pull the logical out of the index:

```
allTimesBinary <- (weekHours %% 24) %in% 8:10
```

Comment: This is fantastic! However I am also looking for an ordered list--Any hints on keeping the test_hr as an ordered list, keeping the non-matching values as '0's?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a binary variable? 1s if the week-hour is in the test setting and 0s if not?

Comment: OK. I added an additional line of code at the bottom that produces a logical vector where TRUE means that a particular week-hour is in the desired set. If you wanted you could coerce this to {1, 0} using `as.integer`.

Comment: Ah thanks you've totally nailed it. This is the final function I'm using:     getTest_hr <- function(weekHours, startTime, stopTime) {
  as.integer((weekHours %% 24)  %in% seq(startTime, stopTime))
}